# How does atmospheric pressure affect horizontal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

[image]In the situation given in picture , How is pressure at surface of container equal to atmospheric pressure , since the container is accelerating forward therefore the surface is also accelerating forward, so the surface has some net force along horizontal to accelerate it and if it has net force along horizontal then that net force would also provide some pressure and hence the pressure>atmospheric pressure

Where am I going wrong can someone explain

Ps: I know that the surface will tilt but how will the horizontal force be affected by it?

Comment: The effect will be negligible owing to the very low density of the air compared to the liquid.

Answer (score 0):

The "surface" is just a boundary, so it doesn't have mass. So regardless of the acceleration, the force on both sides of the boundary must be the same. Therefore the pressure is also the same on both sides of the surface.

As you start to consider a mass of fluid below the surface then there must be a net force and therefore the pressure will increase with "depth", but the increase in the pressure will go to 0 as the mass goes to 0 to consider only the surface rather than a mass of the fluid.

Comment: Can you please answer to the edit I made in question as well , as I do understand your answer but it does not makes sense for the edit I made

Comment: @Raghav it is not appropriate to change a question in a manner that invalidates an answer to the original. I will revert your question, and you can open a new question with the modifications

Comment: I am sorry I didn't knew about it. I have opened a new question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/747279/303736?sem=2 .  Please check this out